# What's the difference between 'false === $var' and '$var === false'?

Tags: php, coding-style, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Is one more readable than the other? At first, I disliked the `false ===` approach but as I see it more and more often, I'm warming up to it. I'm pretty sure they return identical results.

Comment: I guess it's like saying that if `x = y` then `y = x`

Comment: The second is easier to mis-type as an assignment without causing an error.

Comment: http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/

Comment: Good old [Yoda](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)

Comment: I see I was wrong, they don't always return identical results, which breaks the `x = y` and `y = x` analogy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I greatly prefer

```
false === $var
```

Namely because sometimes you are only using equality and not looking for identity.

In which case you write

```
false == $var
```

But sometimes you aren't at the top of your game, and might write

```
false = $var
```

which will give an immediate error, and let's you fix it right away.

However, if you type

```
$var = false
```

you end up beating your head against a wall for an hour trying to figure out why your script isn't working right.

Comment: The use of a decent IDE fixes that argument.

Comment: Code should be accessible independent of IDE

Comment: I don't like `false == $var`, I prefer `! $var`. Make comparison with boolean constant only with triple equality.

Answer (score 9):

There's absolutely no functional difference.

I usually prefer to place the **variable** first, and the **constant value** second. Because that makes sense (When you speak it out loud, would you say "I test that the variable is false"? Or "I test that false is equal to the variable"?)

Comment: +1, i like your vision of "code as better as it loudly sounds"

Comment: Modern IDEs will alert you if you use an assignment inside an if statement, so the only use case for putting the constant first diminishes rapidly.

Comment: Depends if you're a fan of Star Wars: "if false is the value..."

Answer (score 2):

A much better software engineer than me taught me about this. Long story short, placing the constant first is a best practice, although it may look weird at first.  I say that it's a best practice because it results in the most predictable outcomes:

```
$var = null;

if (false === $var) {   // NullPointerException is not thrown; only evaluates to "true" if the value "false" was assigned to $var
    ...
}

if ($var === false {    // NullPointerException will be thrown
    ...
}

if (false = $var) {     // Parse Error
    ...
}

if ($var = false) {     // the value false is assigned to $var
    ...
}
```

Comment: We are discussing PHP, there are no NullPointerExceptions there.

Comment: But the concept still applies.