# Does variables' order matter when doing == and === comparisons?

Tags: php, comparison-operators

Does it really matter to put variables after `==` or `===` when doing comparisons?

```
if (null == $var) {

}

if ($var == null) {

}
```

I've constantly seen coders prefer this way, is it for speed difference?

Updates:

Sorry I didn't make my question clear, what I want to know is not the different between `==` and `===`, but expressions like `null == $var` and `$var == null`, so I've changed the code example.

---

**Conslusion**:

No functional or performance difference. Some consider it a best practice or simply a coding style. BTW it has a cool name: Yoda Conditions :)

FYI: PHP error messages use this style, e.g.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)
```

---

Don't know why this question is marked duplicated to ([The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals?lq=1)) not ([What's the difference between 'false === $var' and '$var === false'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222070/whats-the-difference-between-false-var-and-var-false))

Comment: Possible duplicate to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2063500/1744357

Comment: @vinsanity38 No, it isn't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It prevents typos which cause very hard to debug bugs. That's in case you accidentally write `=` instead of `==`:

```
if ($var == null)  # This is true in case $var actually is null
if ($var =  null)  # This will always be true, it will assign $var the value null
```

Instead, switching them is safer:

```
if (null == $var)   # True if $var is null
if (null =  $var)   # This will raise compiler (or parser) error, and will stop execution.
```

Stopping execution on a specific line with this problem will make it very easy to debug. The other way around is quite harder, since you may find yourself entering `if` conditions, and losing variable's values, and you won't find it easily.

Comment: so this is no performance differene?

Comment: No, either way the cpu will have to read the value of $var from the memory. It's the same difference between `$var1==$var2` and `$var2==$var1`, except that it may be faster comparing to a constant rather than another variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following code will explain it:

```
echo (( 0 == NULL ) ? "0 is null" : "0 is not null")  ."\n";
echo  (0 === NULL) ? "0 is null" : "0 is not null"  ;
```

it will output:

```
0 is null
0 is not null
```

The `===` operator checks for both value and type, but 0 is a number while NULL is of type NULL

The `==` operator checks only for value and zero can be casted to "false" or "null" hence the "truthy" that we get for the first line

Answer (score 0):

Compare results from this to `if`s.

```
 echo "Test '1abc' == 1 - ";
 if ('1abc' == 1) {
    echo 'ok';
 } else {
    echo 'fail';
 }

 echo "\nTest '1abc' === 1 - ";
 if ('1abc' === 1) {
    echo 'ok';
 } else {
    echo 'fail';
 }
```

Then read this page http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php it's very interesting lecture ;)