# PHP - order of values in conditions AKA Yoda notation

Tags: php

### Original question

i read sometime ago in an article i can't find that when doing a comparison the order matters for some reason.
i couldn't find any information on the subject of the order of comparing in PHP.
it obviously won't make a dramatic change but i am curious to know if there is any merit to this.

throughout the project i am working on the comparison is done as `$x === true`.
is there any difference in doing the comparison in the opposite order, as in `true === $x`?

### Conclusion

Apparently what i referred to in the original question is a programming style called "Yoda conditions".
[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) wiki page gives a good explanation about this style.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19352170/10390841) answer made me understand the concept, just note there is a small  mistake there.

Here's my take on it:

The main reason to use this style is to avoid an accidental assignment with `=` when you meant to compare with `==`.

- if you want to check if a variable loosely has the same value as what you compare it to, use:

  ```
  if(false == $var) // evaluates to true if $var is equal to false
  ```

  over

  ```
  if($var == false) // evaluates to true if false is equal to $var
  ```

  to prevent

  ```
  if($var = false) // assigns false to $var and evaluates to false
  ```

  while

  ```
  if(false = $var) // is a syntax error
  ```
- if you want to check if a variable strictly has the same value as what you compare it to, use:

  ```
  if(false === $var) // evaluates to true if $var is identical to false
  ```

  over

  ```
  if($var === false) // evaluates to true if false is identical to $var
  ```

  it doesn't matter in the context of using Yoda style or not as this isn't really an issue with strict comparison because it's pretty hard to confuse `=` with `===` but if you use it for `==` then also use it for `===` to be consistent.

All in all, I think the merit of Yoda notation lies in the emphasized distinction it makes between comparison and assignment in a condition.

Comment: it's a preference

Comment: It's generally referred to as "yoda notation" or "yoda comparison"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does variables' order matter when doing == and === comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352107/does-variables-order-matter-when-doing-and-comparisons) Note that this question is also about the order of comparisons, not `==` vs `===` as many people mistook it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called "Yoda Comparisons". For `===` and `==` it would not matter, but consider this:

```
if($a = 0)
```

In this case `$a` is being set to zero, not compared. In addition, the comparison you think you're making will not evaluate at all, but the comparison operation will proceed as if there was a comparison made. It will always [fall through to `false`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6713d3557a2aeaa9fc370e75e3e58c78da23df9) Flip it:

```
if(0 = $a)
```

Now an error would be thrown.

Comment: This is because `=` is an assignment operator. Only `==` and `===` are comparison operators.

Comment: I could not understand what you meant until i read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19352170/10390841 , and then i read your answer again and i understood it.  consider adding output to make it clearer.

Comment: "the blue is sky" :)